# Is the execution of a function declaration an expression statement? And if so, are my reasons for why it is correct?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f() {
}

f();
```

Is `f()` an expression statement?

1. I understand a statement really needs to have an action or at least successfully have `;` appended to it. Is `f()` a statement because the 'action' it's doing is executing a function? Or is the 'action' it's doing reading the value of `f` which is `undefined`?
2. I understand an expression needs to evaluate to a value. Is `f()` an *expression* statement because it returns `undefined`?

Comment: It's an expression statement because a function call is an expression.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science) "In computer programming, a statement is a syntactic unit of an imperative programming language that expresses some action to be carried out."  `f();` expresses that the action of executing the function should happen.  So yes it's a statement.

Comment: All function calls are expressions, it doesn't matter what the function returns.

Comment: The concepts of statement and expression are based on syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Is this because, in JavaScript, all function calls - at least - evaluate to a value `undefined`?

Comment: No. They evaluate to whatever the function returns.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to match the title. The title asks about the function declaration, but the question seems to be about the function call.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't the function here returning `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, this function returns `undefined`. But you said "all function calls".

Comment: @Barmar The title says 'execution of a function declaration'. Is that not what a function call is?

Comment: The function declaration is `function f() { }`

Comment: Executing the declaration causes the function to be defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219013/discussion-between-barmar-and-tonitone117).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the execution of a function **declaration** an expression statement?

Yes - but note that it's an expression *and* a statement.

For the purposes of this QA; conceptually, this:

```
function foo() { }
```

Is the same as this:

```
var foo = function() { }
```

...which yields a value representing the `function foo`, which is why you can also do this:

```
var foo;
var bar = ( foo = function() { console.log( 'foo' ); } );

foo(); // This call will succeed
bar(); // Ditto.
```

...and this:

```
function higherOrderFunction( func ) {
    func();
}

higherOrderFunction( function foo() {
    console.log( 'foo' );
} );

// or:

higherOrderFunction( function() {
    console.log( 'foo' );
} );
```

...which is (conceptually) the same as this:

```
function higherOrderFunction( func ) {
    func();
}

function foo() {
    console.log( 'foo' );
}

higherOrderFunction( foo );
```